# Issue with IDataErrorInfo with text box in Expander

Tags: wpf

I have one expander and which contain text box, text is validating through IDataErrorInfo, it is working fine when i enter wrong information, it popup with red rectangle.

but issue arises when i tried to collase the expander, and red rectangle is still there. it stayed on Expander

so please provide soem good solution....

Comment: I'm not going to give this a full-fledged answer because I don't have the details, but you need to: Create a custom ErrorTemplate with the red box adorner (or whatever else you like), bind this template's adorner's visibility to the ancestor expander's isexpanded property (you'll need to use RelativeSource to get there), and assign this to the Expander's Validation.ErrorTemplate attached property.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to create a control template where you wrap the contentpresenter element in an adorner decorator. This prevents the validation escaping the closed expander.